# Determine if the absolute value function is differentiable or not.

Tags: real-analysis

Define $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by $F(x,y)=x^2|y|-y^2|x|+2x+3y$

Determine if $F$ is differentiable at $(1,1)$, $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$.Be sure to show work.

I know how to do it at $(1,1)$ but not at the other two points. Help me out please!

Comment: This isn't a homework forum.

Comment: Why don't you show us how you do it at $(1,1)$ and maybe that will give us some idea how to do the other two points. Is it differentiable or not at $(1,1)$ and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $2x + 3y$ is differentiable everywhere, we need only consider $g(x,y) = x^2|y|-y^2|x|.$ The function of $x$ given by $g(x,1) = x^2-|x|$ does not have a derivative at $0,$ simply because $x^2$ does and $|x|$ doesn't. This shows $\partial g/\partial x(0,1)$ fails to exist. Hence $g$ is not differentiable at $(0,1).$ At $(0,0)$ we have $g(x,y) = o(\sqrt {x^2+y^2})$ by a mile. Hence $g$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ with $Dg(0,0) = 0.$

Answer (score 0):

Let's calculate partial derivatives, for example, at $\;(0,1)\;$:

$$F'_x(0,1)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F(x,1)-F(0,1)}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-|x|+2x+3-3}x=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\left(x+2-\frac{|x|}x\right)=\begin{cases}2+1=3,&x<0\\{}\\2-1=1,&x>0\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies$$

the partial derivative wrt $\;x\;$ at $\;(0,1)\;$ doesn't exist and thus $\;F\;$ cannot be differentiable at that point.

Now you do the rest...**but remember**: the existence of partial derivatives is **not** guarantee the function is differentiable there. You would also need to have both partial derivatives to exist around that point and *be continuous* at it (in fact, it is enough that only one of them is continuous...), or else you would have to go to the definition of differential and etc.

Comment: So at (0,0) the partial derivatives do exist then I need to check if they are continuous and the definition of  differentiable?

Comment: @DicksonYuen No, not exactly. The most complete theorem states: if the partial derivatives exist at a point $\;P\;$ *and* in some neighborhood of it, and if at least one of the partial der.'s is continuous at $\;P\;$, **then** the function's differentiable at $\;P\;$ . **But it is not if and only if!** Thus, there are differentiable function with non-continuous partial derivatives, say. Resuming: if you can prove the conditions of the above theorem are fulfilled you get differentiability, but if not that does not mean the function isn't diff. You'll then need to apply the definition...or pray.